# switches calling the same case multiple times

Tags: java, switch-statement

I would like to write some code in java that can in a switch or something calls the same case multiple times, using some code that will be the same for most or all cases in the middle. Right now I have to repeat half of the code for each case because it's surrounded by case sensitive code. The code in my mind would look something like this, variable ranges from 0-3 and break just means stop executing until next call to that case, I understand that it is probably something besides break if it exists,

```
    switch(variable){
    case 0:
    case 1:
        if(other factors)
            //add item to next spot in array
    case 2:
    case 3://all cases
        //add items to next 3 spots in array for all cases
        break;
    case 0:
    case 1:
        if(other factors)
            //add item to next spot in array
    case 2:
    case 3://all cases
        //add more items to next spot in array
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        if(other factors2)
            //add item to next spot in array
        break;
    case 3:
        //add item to next spot in array
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2://all cases
        //add items to next spot in array
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        if(other factors2)
            //add item to next spot in array
        break;
    case 3:
        //add item to next spot in array
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd start with splitting your pseudo switch into real switches:

```
switch(variable){
case 0:
case 1:
    if(other factors)
        //add item to next spot in array
case 2:
case 3://all cases
    //add items to next 3 spots in array for all cases
}

switch(variable){
case 0:
case 1:
    if(other factors)
        //add item to next spot in array
case 2:
case 3://all cases
    //add more items to next spot in array
}

switch(variable){
case 1:
case 2:
    if(other factors2)
        //add item to next spot in array
    break;
case 3:
    //add item to next spot in array
case 0:

}

switch(variable){
case 1:
case 2://all cases
    //add items to next spot in array
    break;
case 1:
case 2:
    if(other factors2)
        //add item to next spot in array
}
```

This should meet your requirements.

I then would extract each switch block in its own method, to make it easier to understand and read.

You might consider extracting all this into a small class hirachy:

```
class DefaultExecutor{
    void do(){
        step1();
        step2();
        step3();
        step4();
    }
    void step1(){//all cases class of the first switch statement}
    //... similar methods for the other switcht statements
}

class CaseZeor extends DefaultExecutor{
    // override step1-4 as required for special treatment of case 0
}

// ... further classes for cases 1-3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with multiple switch statements. When you use `break;` it drops out the switch block in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Switch will not fit for that, you will need to perform the checks with some `if-else` statements (or some separate switch statements as Peter said).

From [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#258896):

> No two of the case constant expressions associated with a switch statement may have the same value.